# How to sum durations in units of Year, Month and Day in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table duration:

```
-------------------------------
| id |    from    |     to    |
|----|------------|-----------|
|  1 | 2011-02-22 |    NULL   |
|  2 | 1999-08-03 |2005-03-30 |
|  3 | 1982-09-03 |1988-01-30 |
|  4 | 1965-12-01 |1980-05-02 |
-------------------------------
```

I want to calculate time differences (to-from) in a row and add them up. My query is:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, from, IF(to IS NULL,'2017-10-
18', to))),' Years ',
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF( MONTH, from, IF(to IS NULL,'2017-10-18', to)) 
% 12),' Months ',
SUM(FLOOR( TIMESTAMPDIFF( DAY, from, IF(to IS NULL,'2017-10-18', 
to)) % 30.4375 )),' Days ') AS Duration
FROM duration;
```

I am getting:

```
------------------------------
|         Duration           |
|----------------------------|
| 30 Years 23 Months 78 Days |
------------------------------
```

But I want to get:

```
-----------------------------
|         Duration          |
|---------------------------|
| 32 Years 1 Months 18 Days |
-----------------------------
```

Please help!

Comment: just try to divide with 12 for month and for days with 30.4375

Comment: I know this.But how to add 30 days as 1 month and 12 months as 1 year? @AnkurJyotiPhukan

Comment: [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cb31/56) - I know there's a way better way of doing this. This is quite hacky. lol

Comment: I altered heading from `How to add Year, Month and Day in MySQL?` to `How to sum durations in units of Year, Month and Day in MySQL?`
`

Comment: @Deja Thaks. It solved my problem. Please add it as answer. I will accept it.

Comment: This heading indicates using date_add() function. Which is not what I am looking for. @Used_By_Already

Comment: The method used by @Deja is a good approximation. But the division by 30.4375 is performed on each row and that result is less accurate than using timstampdiff method for the row calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(y, ' Years ', m, ' Months ', d, ' Days') as Duration 
FROM(
 SELECT 
   IF(SUM(Month) > 12, SUM(d.Year) + FLOOR(SUM(d.Year/12)), SUM(d.Year)) as y,
   IF(SUM(d.DAY) > 30, FLOOR(MOD(((SUM(d.Month) + FLOOR(SUM(d.Day/30.4375)))), 12)), SUM(d.Month)) as m,
   IF(SUM(d.DAY) > 30, FLOOR(MOD(SUM(d.Day), 30)), SUM(d.Month)) as d
 FROM (
  SELECT 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, a, b ) Year,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( MONTH, a, b ) % 12 Month,
    FLOOR( TIMESTAMPDIFF( DAY, a, b ) % 30.4375 ) Day
  from dates
  ) as d
) as c
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cb31/59)

Comment: Whilst this method produces a close approxmation, it isn't fully accurate as shown at this Demo URL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edb305/1 if `b-a = duration` then `a+duration should = b` but in 3/4 rows that isn't true using this method, and if the rows are inaccurate so is the sum of those rows inaccurate. No offence intended to @Deja , my observation is merely about accuracy of method.

Comment: The result is not accurate. As pointed out by Used_By_Already. However it helped me solving my problem.Thanks @Deja

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to present a progression of queries below to display an accurate method for determining duration in years/months/days (although these calculations results in **32 Years 1 Months 22 Days** (*possibly due to change in "now"*) and I haven't added the final concatenation which isn't difficult to achieve. The method used is accurate per row, but does rely on an approximation of days per month (30.4375 *) for the final calculation months and days.

1. `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR , from_dt, to_dt )` gives the number of years per row
2. `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, from_dt + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR , from_dt, to_dt) YEAR  , to_dt )` add the number of years to the start date, then gets the difference of that date to the end date in months
3. `TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY  , from_dt + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, from_dt, to_dt) MONTH , to_dt )` now adds the total numbers of months to the start date and then calculates the ays remaining to reach the end date
4. note, that it is possible to accurately re-calculate the end date if given the start date + years + months + days (see query 4)

nb: I have used multiple "layers" in the queries below make them easier to read (I hope).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42f8df/1)

*MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup*:

```
CREATE TABLE duration
  ( 
     from_dt DATE,  to_dt DATE 
  ); 

INSERT INTO duration 
VALUES  ('2011-02-22', NULL )
      , ('1999-08-03', '2005-03-30' )
      , ('1982-09-03', '1988-01-30' )
      , ('1965-12-01', '1980-05-02' )
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
## adjusted sums( method using timestampdiff ) 
SELECT
      CASE WHEN SUM(d.months) > 12 THEN SUM(d.years) + FLOOR(SUM(d.years/12)) ELSE SUM(d.years) END
      as years
    , CASE WHEN SUM(d.days) > 30 THEN FLOOR(((SUM(d.months) + FLOOR(SUM(d.days/30.4375)))/12)) ELSE SUM(d.months) END
      as months
    , CASE WHEN SUM(d.days) > 30 THEN FLOOR(MOD(SUM(d.days), 30)) ELSE SUM(d.months) END
      as days
    , current_date
FROM (
      SELECT
              TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR , from_dt, to_dt )
              as years
            , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, from_dt + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR , from_dt, to_dt) YEAR  , to_dt )
              as months
            , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY  , from_dt + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, from_dt, to_dt) MONTH , to_dt )
              as days
      FROM (
            SELECT
                 from_dt
                , COALESCE(to_dt,CURRENT_DATE) to_dt
            FROM duration
          ) d2
    ) d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42f8df/1/0)**:

```
| years | months | days | current_date |
|-------|--------|------|--------------|
|    32 |      2 |   22 |   2017-10-19 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
## simple sums( method using timestampdiff )
SELECT
        sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR , from_dt, to_dt ))
        years
      , sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, from_dt + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR , from_dt, to_dt) YEAR  , to_dt ))
        months
      , sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY  , from_dt + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, from_dt, to_dt) MONTH , to_dt ))
        days
      , current_date
FROM (
      SELECT
           from_dt
          , COALESCE(to_dt,CURRENT_DATE) to_dt
      FROM duration
    ) d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42f8df/1/1)**:

```
| years | months | days | current_date |
|-------|--------|------|--------------|
|    30 |     23 |   82 |   2017-10-19 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
## method using timestampdiff
SELECT
        d.*
      , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR , from_dt, to_dt )                                                        AS diff_yr
      , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, from_dt + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR , from_dt, to_dt) YEAR  , to_dt ) AS diff_mn
      , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY  , from_dt + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, from_dt, to_dt) MONTH , to_dt ) AS diff_dy
FROM (
      SELECT
           from_dt
          , COALESCE(to_dt,CURRENT_DATE) to_dt
          , current_date
      FROM duration
    ) d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42f8df/1/2)**:

```
|    from_dt |      to_dt | current_date | diff_yr | diff_mn | diff_dy |
|------------|------------|--------------|---------|---------|---------|
| 2011-02-22 | 2017-10-19 |   2017-10-19 |       6 |       7 |      27 |
| 1999-08-03 | 2005-03-30 |   2017-10-19 |       5 |       7 |      27 |
| 1982-09-03 | 1988-01-30 |   2017-10-19 |       5 |       4 |      27 |
| 1965-12-01 | 1980-05-02 |   2017-10-19 |      14 |       5 |       1 |
```

**Query 4**:

```
## testing (method using timestampdiff)
## is able to reproduce to_dt ?
select
      from_dt
    , to_dt
    , from_dt + INTERVAL diff_yr YEAR
              + INTERVAL diff_mn MONTH
              + INTERVAL diff_dy DAY
      recalculated_to_dt
    , current_date
FROM (
      SELECT
              d.*
            , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR , from_dt, to_dt )                                                                    AS diff_yr
            , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, from_dt + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR , from_dt, to_dt) YEAR  , to_dt ) AS diff_mn
            , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY  , from_dt + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, from_dt, to_dt) MONTH , to_dt ) AS diff_dy
      FROM (
            SELECT
                 from_dt
                , COALESCE(to_dt,CURRENT_DATE) to_dt
            FROM duration
          ) d
    ) d2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42f8df/1/3)**:

```
|    from_dt |      to_dt | recalculated_to_dt | current_date |
|------------|------------|--------------------|--------------|
| 2011-02-22 | 2017-10-19 |         2017-10-19 |   2017-10-19 |
| 1999-08-03 | 2005-03-30 |         2005-03-30 |   2017-10-19 |
| 1982-09-03 | 1988-01-30 |         1988-01-30 |   2017-10-19 |
| 1965-12-01 | 1980-05-02 |         1980-05-02 |   2017-10-19 |
```

- **30.4375** I believe that is ~ (days in a century) / 120

Comment: Thanks a lot.But the first query is already provided by @Deja. Which is the only one providing the solution perfectly.

Comment: As I attempted to explain and demonstrate the more accurate answer here is `32 Years 1 Months 22 Days`  the method used here calculates each row accurately and only applies any approximation on the final sum,

Comment: Got your point. It was helpful. Thanks a lot. @Used_By_Already

Answer (score 0):

I chage table nane and two feilds nanes:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(
         extract(year from from_days(   DATEDIFF(  IFNULL(t,now()),  IFNULL(frm, now())  ))),
         ' Years ',
          extract(month from from_days( DATEDIFF(  IFNULL(t,now()),  IFNULL(frm, now())  ))),
          ' Months ',
          extract(day from from_days(   DATEDIFF(  IFNULL(t,now()),  IFNULL(frm, now())  ))),
          ' Days' 
) AS Duration 
FROM 
  test
```

It seems that this is what you wanted ...

Answer (score 0):

The correct SQL is

```
SELECT
      CASE WHEN SUM(d.months) > 12 THEN SUM(d.years) + FLOOR(SUM(d.months/12)) ELSE SUM(d.years) END
      AS years
    , CASE WHEN SUM(d.days) > 30 THEN FLOOR(MOD((SUM(d.months) + FLOOR(SUM(d.days/30.4375))),12)) ELSE FLOOR(MOD(SUM(d.months), 12)) END
      AS months
    , CASE WHEN SUM(d.days) > 30 THEN FLOOR(MOD(SUM(d.days), 30)) ELSE FLOOR(MOD(SUM(d.days), 30)) END
      AS days
   
FROM (
      SELECT
              TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR , from_date, to_date )
              AS years
            , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, from_date + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR , from_date, to_date) YEAR  , to_date )
              AS months
            , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY  , from_date + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, from_date, to_date) MONTH , to_date )
              AS days
        FROM (
            SELECT
                 from_date
                , COALESCE(to_date,CURRENT_DATE) to_date
            FROM experiences WHERE `user_id` ='1'
          ) d2
    ) d
```